# installing chatterbot it raise spacy installation error in python- pip install chatterbot - not working

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, spacy, chatterbot

Ii have installed latest Redistributable Microsoft C++ and upgraded my pip but not resolved...anyone please give solution

```
`pip install chatterbot`


        preshed/maps.cpp(181): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory

        **error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
        [end of output]**
    
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure
    
      Encountered error while trying to install package.
    
      preshed
    
`
× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> See above for output.`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the ***chatterbot*** package no longer supports the new version of Python. You can download and install *Python38* or *python37* or earlier versions to use the ***chatterbot*** package.

https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

After testing, I successfully installed the ***chatterbot*** package with [**python 3.8.0**](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/) and [**python 3.7.9**](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-379/).

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer...I had checked that chatterbot run in  lower version of python == py3.7-3.8....Is there anyother alternate....I have problem with installing spacy that i need for other purposes....